# Символ % в Postgresql и пример

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть такая таблица

```
 CREATE TABLE Products
    (
      prod_id    char(10)      NOT NULL ,
      vend_id    char(10)      NOT NULL ,
      prod_name  char(255)     NOT NULL ,
      prod_price decimal(8,2)  NOT NULL ,
      prod_desc  varchar(1000) NULL 
    );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При таком запросе:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod_desc LIKE '%j%k';
```

не выдает данные из столбца `prod_desc` хотя последнее слово jacket

Как только ставлю `%` после `k` сразу показывает результат запроса: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему вот этот запрос не работает?

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod_desc LIKE '%j%k';
```

Ведь после `k` ничего нет (нет никаких слов, данных)

Answer (score 2):

> LIKE '%j%k';
>   не выдает данные из столбца prod_desc хотя последнее слово jacket

А почему должно совпадать? Вы явно попросили те строки, которые завершаются символом `k`. Строка оканчивающаяся словом `jacket` символом очевидно `k` не завершается.

Добавьте строку с prod_desc, оканчивающимся символом `k` и содержащую где-то ранее символ j - такая строка будет совпадать с этим условием like.

Comment: Спасибо, я писал не '%j%t', а '%j%k' тупанул жестко)

Answer (score 0):

Важно понимать как работает символ % в SQL

asd% - вернет все строки, которые начинаются на asd

%asd - вернет все строки, которые заканчиваются на asd

%asd% - вернет строки, где подстрока asd есть на любой позиции

В вашем случае, что бы **prod_desc** выдавал jacket нужно написать

```
LIKE '%j%k%'
```

В таком случае вы говорите - неважно с какого символа начинается и каким заканчивается, должны быть j и k и не важно, есть ли что-то между ними.

[Пример на sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8af58/10)